# Habilitar componente p:dialog en ventana emergente, primefaces

Tags: java, web, jsf, primefaces, diálogo

Saludos, estoy trabajando en primefaces, pero al momento de mostrar una ventana emergente esta se encuentra deshabilitada para poder realizar cualquier actividad sobre la información que en ella se muestra. Adjunto la captura de pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el código de la ventana emergente:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
```

```
<ui:composition>
    <p:dialog header="Cuestionario resuelto" widgetVar="dlgTestResuelto" modal="true" 
              width="85%" closable="true" resizable="false" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold" 
              appendTo="@(body)">  
        <br/>
        <h:form id="frmTestResuelto">
            <h:panelGroup id="display">
                <p:dataTable id="datosLSI">
                        ...
                        ...
                        ...
                </p:dataTable>
                <p:commandButton value="Salir" onclick="PF('dlgTestResuelto').hide()" type="reset"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
</ui:composition>
```

Por la ayuda que me puedan brindar, quedo agradecido.

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con  `<p : dialog ... modal="false">` o quitándolo directamente.